# What is the purpose of ','. expression in Python grammar specification?

Tags: python, cpython

Can you help me with the `args` part in [Python grammar specification](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/grammar.html)?

```
args:
    | ','.(starred_expression | ( assignment_expression | expression !':=') !'=')+ [',' kwargs ] 
    | kwargs
```

Especially this part: `','.(starred_expression | ( assignment_expression | expression !':=') !'=')+`. What does `','.` mean?

I checked https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Backus%E2%80%93Naur_form and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing_expression_grammar, but could not find a reference to that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[PEP 617](https://peps.python.org/pep-0617/#s-e) describes the syntax used by the grammar specification. In particular, [`s.e+`](https://peps.python.org/pep-0617/#s-e) means one or more `e`s separated by `s`s.

So `args` is a sequence of one or more various expressions separated by commas.